# Batch File: How to read only sections in a INI file

Tags: batch-file, config, ini

I am very much a novice at Batch Scripting and i'm trying to write a simple script to READ from an INI file based on the Parameters that is passed when the batch file is called.

This is an example for what the INI file would look like:

```
[SETTING1]
Value1=Key1
Value2=Key2
Value3=Key3

[SETTING2]
Value1=Key1
Value2=Key2
Value3=Key3

[SETTING3]
Value1=Key1
Value2=Key2
Value3=Key3
```

I am running into a problem when it comes to reading ONLY the section that is called. It will read from any section that matches the "Value" and "Key" and i don't know how to limit it to only read the section with the settings.

The file is being called with this Parameter: run.bat run.ini setting2. My code below is what I have so far and I feel as if i have officially hit a wall. Can anyone help with this? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
    @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET INIFile="%~f1"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (!INIFile!) do (
        if %%a==[%2] (
        SET yesMatch=%%a
            for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (!yesMatch!) do (
                if %%a==Value1 set Key1=%%b
                if %%a==Value2 set Key2=%%b
                if %%a==Value3 set Key3=%%b
)
        ECHO !yesMatch!
        ECHO !Key1!
        ECHO !Key2!
        ECHO !Key3!
        pause
)
)

pause
exit /b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET INIFile="%~f1"
SET "FLAG="

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*eol=|delims==" %%a in (%INIFile%) do (
 IF "%%b"=="" (
  REM No "=" so section
  IF /i "%%a"=="[%2]" (SET flag=Y) ELSE (SET "flag=")
 ) ELSE IF defined flag (
  REM data line - only if FLAG is defined
  REM set values defined
  SET "%%a=%%b"
  REM pick particular values
  if /i "%%a"=="Value1" set "Key1=%%b"
  if /i "%%a"=="Value2" set "Key2=%%b"
  if /i "%%a"=="Value3" set "Key3=%%b"
 )

)
SET key
SET val

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a way to get your values.

The data in the file is either `[section]` or `name=value` so settling `delims` to `=` will assign either section-only to `%%a` or *name* to `%%a` and *value* to `%%b`.

The flag is only set (defined) after its appropriate section is encountered, and cleared on the next section. Only of it is defined will the assignment take place.

The advantage of the simple `set %%a=%%b` is that it results in setting whatever values are defined in the section - no changes to the code need to take place if new values are added. Your original version has the advantage of picking particular values and setting only those. You pays your money, you takes your choice.

Note that the `/i` switch on an `if` statement makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Nota also the use of `set "value=string"` which ensures that trailing spaces on a line are not included in the value assigned.

---

edit : By default, the `end of line` character is `;` so any line starting `;` is ignored by `for/f`. The consequence is that the values for the `;-commented-out` section would override the values set for the previous section.

Setting `eol` to `|` should cure the problem. It really doesn't matter what `eol` is set to; it's exactly one character which may not appear anywhere in the INI-file (else that line would appear truncated.)

It *is* possible, if necessary, to set `eol` to control-Z but selecting an unused character is easier...

Consequently, a one-line change - the `eol` parameter is included in the `for /f` options.

Comment: Does exactly what I need it to do! ..THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Any particular way to tweak this, to not evaluate commented out sections?  I noticed that if i add a comment to the INI file starting with a semi-colon it makes the script not evaluate anything below the quote.