# Batch file read data from text file based on text category

Tags: batch-file

How do I read data from text file based on text category,

i.e inside this hello.txt have the following data:

```
Fruits
Apple
Orange

Food
Spaghetti
Hotdog
Burger
```

If category equal **Food** then result is Spahetti, Hotdog, and Burger

`FOR /F %%i in (hello.txt) do (echo %%i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch File: How to read only sections in a INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952812/batch-file-how-to-read-only-sections-in-a-ini-file)

Comment: Another good resource is the function library on the dostips.com website.  In a few of those scripts they have a function called [:extractfilesection](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php#Batch.FtpBatchDownloadOnlyNewFiles). This function allows you to call the function with the start and end of the section you want. The default end is an empty line.